# UISlider's minView goes beyond it's bounds and thumb's center

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, uislider

I wanted a custom slider and the requirement was the height of minView should be 8 pt & maxView should be 4 pt, it's the visible corners should be rounded.

I gave the slider's min & max image as clear image of alpha as 0.0

For maxView, I created a UIView and gave it width equal to slider's width, and made it's corners rouneded.

For minView, I created a UIView and it's leading is equal to leading of slider and trailing should be equal to the center of the thumb.

[image]

Here is the logic for what I did.

```
func changeValue() {
    let difference = slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue
    let thumbWidth = CGFloat(44/2)
    let scale = (slider.frame.size.width-thumbWidth)/CGFloat(difference)
    let width = scale * CGFloat(slider.value)
    minSlideWidth.constant = width
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But the minView's width doesn't increase and decrease it's width with the thumb's center. If you see the image it had already crossed the UIslider's thumb.

[image]

Comment: Why do this with an additional view? Use the `setMinimumTrackImage` and `setMaximumTrackImage`.

Comment: I did it and rounded corners doesn't look good.

Comment: Which rounded corners do you mean?

Comment: The rounded corners for the Slider's minImage & maxImage.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach ?

Configure properties of [UISlide control](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider).

1. `setMinimumTrackImage` with 8pt image.
2. `setMaximumTrackImage` with 4pt image.

The track images could be re-created by [stretchable image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) in order to **keep the rounded corners**. You can find it in the section `Defining a Stretchable Image` section from [UIImage reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage). It is very useful for track image of slide bar.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try, but whats wrong in my logic? Why it's going beyond the thumb? Could you please help me with that

Comment: I suppose that you should get the slide track bar frame by it's method: [trackRect(forBounds:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621349-trackrect). The frame of control is not equal to the frame of the middle track bar.

Comment: Or, you could get the center of thumb image by [thumbRect(forBounds:trackRect:value:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621344-thumbrect).